# Converting Analog input to digital for CAN on the mbed LPC1768

Tags: can-bus, mbed

I need help with a code to convert an AnalogIn input on the mbed LPC1768 to digital to be used by the CAN controller.The example syntax I'm using is

```
if(can1.write(CANMessage(1337, &counter, 2))) {
..........
}
```

where "`counter`" is the data to be transmitted and defined by me as a signed int (the example however defines it as a char). But I keep getting an error message

```
Error: No instance of constructor "mbed::CANMessage::CANMessage" matches the argument list in "project_test.cpp"
```

The controller CANMessage syntax is

```
CANMessage(int _id, const char *_data, char _len = 8, CANType _type = CANData, CANFormat _format = CANStandard) {

  len    = _len & 0xF;
  type   = _type;
  format = _format;
  id     = _id;
  memcpy(data, _data, _len);
}
```

I really do not understand the controller syntax and how to apply it. Any help in explaining would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since CANMessage only accepts a char* for the data paramter, you can convert your signed int value (which is 4 bytes) to an unsigned char like this:

```
unsigned char buf[0x8];
buf[0]=value & 0x000000ff;
buf[1]=(value >> 8)  & 0x000000ff;
buf[2]=(value >> 16) & 0x000000ff;
buf[3]=(value >> 24) & 0x000000ff;
```

and then

```
if (can1.write(CANMessage(1337, &buf, 8))) {
..........
}
```